# How to get current date from GMT time according to countries

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing GMT date in my database, my data base name is 'follow'.

```
id imageid  status     date

1    12      missyou   1362525409

2    12      loveyou   1362525416

3    12      fans      1362525422
```

Now my problem is, I want to get today date, this week, this month, 3 months of this year from the above GMT date and I want to display the date in this format  "date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')" 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the stored timestamp to the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. Just use `date("Y d h i", $timestamp)`

If you want to calculate with the date, check out the [DateTime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) function to add days/weeks/months